# POST method not being invoked from the URL in API Gateway

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, flask-restx

I have a basic `flask-restx` app (`main.py`) as follows:

```
ns = Namespace(
    "greetings",
    description="Get Greetings."
)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("name", type=str, help="name")


@ns.route('/restx/hello/')
class restx_hello(Resource):
    @ns.expect(parser, validate=True)
    def get(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        name = args['name']
        g = 'Greetings to you!'
        return 'Hello ' + name + '! I am from restx. ' + g

    @ns.expect(parser, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        name = args['name']
        return 'This is the POST method, ' + name
```

As it can be seen in the code, I am calling both `GET` & `POST` methods on the route: `/greetings/restx/hello/`. I have deployed this code on `API Gateway` and `lambda` using `Serverless`.

The `serverless.yml` file:

```
service: flask-api

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi_handler.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    pythonBin: python3
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

plugins:
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

On the `API Gateway`, when I test the `GET` & `POST` methods separately from the dashboard, they print their respective outputs.

**Screenshot of the `GET` method**

[image]

**Screenshot of the `POST` method**

[image]

I have the following URL for this service: [https://abcdefgh.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/{proxy+}](https://abcdefgh.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/%7Bproxy+%7D).

When I invoke the URL itself from the browser as: https://abcdefgh.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/greetings/restx/hello/?name=Alex it always calls the `GET` method as follows:

[image]

The `POST` method is never being invoked. What is the mistake that I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On browser, it always use `GET` method.

For `POST` method, you can use POSTMAN tool at: https://www.postman.com

Or use `curl` on terminal:

```
curl -X POST url
```